# Cloudlab ssh access from one node to another

Tags: apache-flink, ssh-keygen

Is it possible to configure nodes so that one node can ssh into other nodes on CloudLab, which is required for a Flink cluster deployment. I tried generating public/private keys (ssh-keygen -t rsa -P “”) and copy public key of one node into ~/.ssh/authorized of another node, but it still asks for passphrase (which I'm not sure). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is a specific requirement on your end, because Flink doesn't have any dependency with CloudLab?

Comment: Yes, that's true. But in order to deploy a standalone Flink cluster, it's required for the master node to ssh into children nodes if I didn't any other approaches.

Comment: Flink doesn't require SSH from master node to children nodes. Are you reading this somewhere? Have you checked https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/ ?